# Unsure why "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null" is occurring and how to fix

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bootstrap-4

When the button is clicked, the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null" is produced. The intended effect is to change the href, innerHTML, and class of a link. The button pressed and the link are on separate pages.

Not sure why this is occurring, my script tag for the .js file is at the end of my body tag, and there seems to be no spelling/casing issues with my id.

Would like to know how to fix and why its not working as intended.

HTML (page with link to be edited)

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-orange navbar-dark"> <!--Custom colour for navbar bg-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Icon</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
            <ul class= "navbar-nav ml-auto">
                ...
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="login.html" id="loginIcon">
                        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
     ...
    <script src="login-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

HTML (page with button)

```
<body>
    <div class="text-center p-3">
        <a href="index.html" id="loginButton" onclick="loginClick()"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-auto button-white button-text-black" href="#" role="button">Login</a>
        
    </div>
    <div class="text-center p-3">
        <a href="sign-up.html" id="signUpButton"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-auto button-white button-text-black" href="#" role="button">Or Sign Up Here</a>
    </div> 
    <script src="login-script.js"></script> 
</body>
```

JS

```
function loginClick(){
    document.getElementById("loginIcon").setAttribute("href","account.html");
    document.getElementById("loginIcon").setAttribute("class","fa fa-user-plus");
    document.getElementById("loginIcon").innerHTML="Account";
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please create a Stack Snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: It looks like the button is not on the same page as the link. How is the link page related to the button page?

Comment: yes, thats right @Teemu

Comment: If you don't have both of the pages opened in a browser, and there isn't a special relation between the pages (iframe or pop-up/tab), there's no way you can refer an element across pages.

Comment: would creating a boolean variable in the .js file in order to trigger the changing of the link work? eg. onclick = function that changes bool variable to true, then code to cause link to change when bool is true

Comment: No, files are live only when they're loaded to a browser. In the browser a file is parsed and compiled to a piece of program the browser runs.

Comment: then, what would be the suggested way to trigger the link change when the button is on a different page?

Comment: You need the relation, i.e. the link page is inside an iframe which is placed on the button page, or is a tab/pop-up window opened by the button page, you can't interact with an arbitrary web page.